# How to replace null value of a String in java?

Tags: java, string

I know it's a dumb question but still.

But I want to know is it possible to replace the string which is set to null ?

```
String str=null;

String str2= str.replace('l','o');

System.out.println(str2);
```

Currently it is giving me `NullPointerException`.

I want to know is it possible to some how replace the value of String which is set to null ?

If Yes, how ?

Help appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: `str` is `null` so it is throwing exact exception try to initialize the String also read something about String .

Comment: Not possible. Maybe try an empty string.

Comment: The question doesn't even make sense. If you have a null reference, there *is* no string in which to replace values. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: No it is not, because `null` is not a string in your case. If you use `String str="null";` then `null` is a string and you can replace the character

Comment: If you want str2 to be null if str is null, then just test for null: `String str2 = (str == null) ? null : str.replace('l', 'o');`

Comment: Which result are you expecting?

Comment: your `str=null; ` here  `str.replace()` your are inviting `NullPointerException.`

Comment: @JonSkeet, surprisingly, the question was legit

Comment: @YassinHajaj: No, I really don't think it was. The answers provided don't answer the question asked - they guess at what the OP *might* have been trying to achieve. They don't perform a replacement on a value of `String` which is set to `null` - they effectively convert that to a reference to `"null"` first, which isn't the same thing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `String.valueOf()`:

```
String str2 = String.valueOf(str).replace('l','o');
```

From the javadoc of [`String.valueOf(Object obj)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-java.lang.Object-):

> if the argument is null, then a string equal to "null"; otherwise, the value of obj.toString() is returned.

which of course for a `String` is itself.

Comment: That doesn't do what the OP actually *asked* though. The question still doesn't make sense, IMO.

Comment: @Jon I'm pretty sure it captures OP's intention. Point taken though: If he ticks this, I'll edit the Q to align more to this.

Comment: The thing is, when we know more about what the OP was really trying to do, we may well be able to suggest a better approach anyway. This is an XY problem, where half of it is non-sensical :(

Answer (score 2):

I dont know what you are trying to achieve but you can concat empty string to it and it will work

```
String str = null;
str += "";
String str2 = str.replace('l', 'o');

System.out.println(str2);
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/EiaQwQ)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.java-examples.com/java-string-valueof-example

Check it once you may come to know clear idea about Strings

Comment: @bohemian the way you told is actually correct. And Jon skeet is also right as I have assign a null reference there is no String to replace value.

Answer (score 0):

If str is null,str2 will be an empty string

```
String str=null;

String str2= StringUtils.isEmpty(str) ? '' : str.replace('l','o');

System.out.println(str2);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.